# Is it possible to segment access?

Tags: docusignapi

Using the REST API for remote signing and it's been working great for about a year now.

We have a user of our system that wants to send documents for e-signature, and I'd like to limit their access to their own documents, let them get the notifications of document completion, etc.

I know I can create additional users in the admin section but I'm not sure of where to look from there. Is any of the rest possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, add the person as a regular (not admin) sender in your DocuSign account. They'll only be able to see envelopes (transactions) that they sent.

They can also see envelopes that were explicitly shared with them by another sender

### Added: authenticate as a different person

Your API application sends envelopes by using the credentials of an account member. If this is a non-person such as "finance@yourCompany.com" then we call that a "system user."

Your question was how to send envelopes from a sender who is not an administrator. The answer is to authenticate to the DocuSign API as that person. This can be done with the OAuth JWT or Authorize Code grant flows.

Ask a new question if you have more questions on how to do this.

Comment: I think I see: so do I then plug their userid in as ds_client_id?